# computing an average from an array list

Tags: java, arrays, average

I get an error for

```
sum = sum + arr[i]; // "i cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

Why is that?
"i" was declared earlier and I'm trying to use the value `arr[i]` to find and average of an arraylist from a text file called *numbers.txt*

```
public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] numbers = readFiles("./bin/q1/numbers.txt");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }

    private static int[] readFiles(String file) {

        try {
            File f = new File(file);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            int ctr = 0;

            //counting number of integers in numbers.txt
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                ctr++;  
                s.nextInt();
            }

            int [] arr = new int[ctr];
            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f);

            //reads integers from file and assigns it to array
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
                arr[i] = s1.nextInt();

            int sum = 0;
            sum = sum + arr[i];
            float average = sum / (float) arr.length;
            System.out.println("average of array is: " + average + "\n");
            System.out.println("length of array is: " + arr.length + " integers \n");
            return arr;

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: Please add the language you are coding.  Moreover, you haven't declare the `i`, as `i` you mentioned was only exists in the the `for loop`, it will be destroyed after the for loop.  Depends on what you trying to do, you can declare another `for-loop`, declare another `i`, or include your code in previous `for-loop` with ***curly bracket***.

Comment: coding in java and what do u mean by include previous code in for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter is, the `i` you declared only exists in the previous `for-loop`

```java
//reads integers from file and assigns it to array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
    arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
```

The `i` will be destroyed after `for-loop`, which means you cannot access the `i` anymore, you may find more details in [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

To solve your problem, you have many options, for example:

***Created another `for-loop`***

```java
//reads integers from file and assigns it to array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
    arr[i] = s1.nextInt();

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
    sum = sum + arr[i];

float average = sum / (float) arr.length;
```

***Include in the previous `for-loop`***

```java
//reads integers from file and assigns it to array
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
    sum = sum + arr[i];
}

float average = sum / (float) arr.length;
```

Comment: thank you sir! I will mess around with it but this makes way more sense!

Comment: how come when I add another if statement inside the try catch, i get return null in the console
?